# Cannot Edit Python Script tool using its context menu from ArcMap/ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool

I am unable to edit scripts in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.

I navigate to the script, right-click on it and select "Edit", then nothing happens. I am using notepad++ as my editor (set in geoprocessing options). I have looked into this issue (http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38581) and have attempted the steps therein. However I am still getting the same result, nothing happens.

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop Basic Version 10.3.1 and Python 2.6

What steps should I attempt to solve this issue?

Comment: What versions of ArcGIS and Python are you using?

Comment: Sounds like permission problems. Aren't those scripts stored in system folders? See if you can make a copy, edit the copy, and then replace the files.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.3.x uses Python 2.7, maybe you could install the right version of Python and see if it happens again

Comment: Can you open them from windows explorer?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same symptom (but using IDLE instead of Notepad++) in earlier versions of ArcGIS for Desktop, and I have a suspicion that it started to appear around the same time I began to install ArcGIS Pro, and its version of Python, on the same machine.

In any event, using my current configuration of ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop and ArcGIS Pro 1.3, everything like this related to using two Python versions (those installed by Desktop and Pro), now seems to work as expected.

If upgrading ArcGIS for Desktop (and ArcGIS Pro, if you are also using that) is an option then I think that presents you with a painless way forward on this.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure upgrading is really an option for us, unfortunately.