# Cannot Edit Python Script from ArcMap/ArcCatalog with IDLE?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, idle

I'm trying to set my Script Tool Editor in the Geoprocessing Options dialog so that I can edit a script tool within ArcMap. Currently, whenever I right-click on my script and select "Edit..." from the resulting menu, nothing happens. I've set my editor to what I think is the correct .exe file (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw), but selecting "Edit..." on the script tool menu still has no effect.

My issue seems to be similar to [Cannot Edit Python Script tool using its context menu from ArcMap/ArcCatalog?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174579) which was never answered but I am using ArcMap 10.1 SP for Desktop Basic and Python 2.7 (I think).

Comment: The original question hasn't been answered, though - is there another way to repost/resubmit the original?

Comment: These are your options w.r.t. the original: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-answers  The alternative is to edit much more detail into your own question to convince the community that it should not be considered a duplicate and re-opened for separate processing.